# Passing array to ViewController, loading ViewController, then refreshing UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is my first time posting and I was just having issues with a "get your feet wet" project (simple tip calculator) I am doing in my spare time.

What I want to do is, to pass an array from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2`, then I want to load `ViewController2` and refresh `UITableView` that is located on `ViewController2`.

I use `ViewController1` to take the user submitted data and calculate the results. I want to take those results and send it over to `ViewController2` to display the results. I'm doing this because it's a tabbed application and I want the results to display on another tab.

Here is how I pass the data from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2`

```
    -(void) displayCalculationsView:(NSMutableArray *)array{

        UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
       CalculationsViewController *viewController2 = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2" ];

       [viewController2 setArrayValueAndRefreshTable:array];
       [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
   }
```

Here is what is on the receiving end:

```
-(void)setArrayValueAndRefreshTable:(NSMutableArray *)array{

    if (calculationsDisplayArray == nil) {
        calculationsDisplayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    [calculationsDisplayArray removeAllObjects];
    [calculationsDisplayArray addObjectsFromArray:array];

    for (NSString *data in pushedDisplayArray) {
        NSLog(@"PUSHED ARRAY DATA: %@", data);
    }

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

The data seems to be received fine because it displays all the correct data in the NSLog. However, when the `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];` part hits, it wipes out my `calculationsDisplayArray`, after the page has loaded.

Is there any way to prevent it from becoming nil? I'm using ARC and it doesn't let me use `[arrayname retain];` I'm not sure I want to use segue because I don't have access to my array in the segue method (or do I?), so I would not be able to send it over to the other view.

Once again, I am new at this. So if there is any more clarification needed, please tell me and I will update this post. Thank you.

Comment: You have created another CalculationsViewController. You should retrieve it using `CalculationsViewController * viewController2 = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]; `.

Comment: To elaborate on KudoCC's point, viewController2 is already instantiated when the tab bar controller is instantiated, so you need to access that one, not make a new one.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you have created a new view controller instead of accessing the one in your tab bar. You should access your existing view controller:

```
CalculationsViewController * viewController2 = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
```